# How to make a dual boot Windows Xp drive and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which should I install first, Windows XP or Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/39480/which-should-I-install-first-Windows-xp-or-Windows-7)

I want to make a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Now I installed Windows 7 64bit edition and found 2 programs that I need don't work in Windows 7. I think it is more the fact because of the 64bit part and not of Windows 7.

So it probably will be a while(possibly years) till everything will work 100% on 64bit stuff but I like 64bit and that's where everyone is heading anyways so might as well start using it and actually make use of my 4gigs of ram.

Anyways, I installed Windows XP just now and I notice that every time I load up my pc. It just goes straight to Windows XP and does not give a list of my operating systems to choose from.

So I am assuming I have to do another step to get this to work.

No I did not copy over Windows 7 when I installed XP. It is still there

Comment: This has been answered before: http://superuser.com/questions/39480, http://superuser.com/questions/41595. Maybe you'll find more information there.

Answer (score 1):

[LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5126781/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-with-xp-or-vista) has a complete step by step procedure of exactly what you want to do...   Refer to that link and probably you would find the solution to your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP doesn't understand the Win7 bootloader, so installing XP overwrote it with XP's own bootloader.  Your Win7 install is probably OK, you just need to [boot your Win7 Installation Disc](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/668-system-recovery-options.html) and run the [Startup Repair](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html) process.

Here's an [alternate link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html) for the same process that may be clearer.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/27678/windows-xp-boot-loader) pertains to a similar problem.